# Django ForeignKey Constraint Failed error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, blogs

I am creating a simple blog site with multi-user facility using django framework. In my project, If the admin deletes any user, all of that user's blogs should not be deleted, I've tried using

```
models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but it obviously deletes all the blogs if the admin deletes the user. Can anyone help me please? Thank in advance...

Comment: have you tried using `SET_NULL` instead of `CASCADE`

Answer (score 12):

This is due to the **`on_delete=CASCADE`**. That means that if the object to which the `ForeignKey` refers is deleted, then it should delete the referring object as well. Such `CASCADE` can thus result in a large amount of objects that get deleted, since the deletion of objects can in fact trigger other deletes, and so on.

There are several options, listed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#arguments):

1. **`CASCADE`**: delete referring objects;
2. **`PROTECT`**: do not allow to delete the user given there are objects that refer to the user;
3. **`SET_NULL`**: set to `NULL` (`None` in Python), in that case, one has to set `null=True` in the `ForeignKey(..)` constructor;
4. **`SET_DEFAULT`**: sets the `ForeignKey` back to the `default=...` value;
5. **`SET(..)`**: set the `ForeignKey` to some value that is passed to the `SET(..)` constructor (one can also use a callable);
6. **`DO_NOTHING`**: here we keep a reference, but some database backend will *not* allow that, since these check `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

So we can for example use `SET_NULL`, and thus set the `author` to `NULL`/`None` in case we delete the author:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    # ...
```

It is also better to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, since if you later change the `User` model, this will automatically change the reference to the new model.

Comment: Nope, It's working as desired. Now, if I try to add a blog from the admin panel, I'm getting this error, AttributeError at /admin/blogs/blog/add/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'

Comment: @KamleshGupta: can you share your view? If the `author` is set to `None`, then obviously, it has no `username` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to run makemigrations and migrate again because you may have deleted models and tried to delete users. I hope it helps because I have solved my issue like this:

```sh
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```